# TensorFlow network is receiving wrong tensor shape after using `dataset.map()`

Tags: tensorflow

Following the example at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#preprocessing_data_with_datasetmap, I want to create a `tf.Dataset` which takes in paths to images, and maps these to image tensors.

My first attempt was the following, which is very similar to the example in the above link:

```
def input_parser(image_path):

    image_data_string = tf.read_file(image_path)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_data_string, channels=3)
    image_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_decoded, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image_float


def train_model():

    image_paths = ['test_image1.png', .test_image2.png', 'test_image3.png']
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(map_func=input_parser)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    input_images = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        for i in range(3):
            x = sess.run(input_images)
            print(x.shape)
```

This seemed to work ok, and printed out:

```
(64, 64, 3)
(64, 64, 3)
(64, 64, 3)
```

Which are indeed the dimensions of my images.

So then I tried to actually feed this data into a network to train, and modified the code accordingly:

```
def input_parser(image_path):

    image_data_string = tf.read_file(image_path)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_data_string, channels=3)
    image_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_decoded, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image_float


def train_model():

    image_paths = ['test_image1.png', .test_image2.png', 'test_image3.png']
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(map_func=input_parser)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    input_images = iterator.get_next()

    x = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_images, filters=50, kernel_size=[5, 5], name='layer1')
    x = tf.layers.flatten(x, name='layer2')
    prediction = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=4, name='layer3')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        for i in range(3):
            p = sess.run(prediction)
            print(p)
```

This then gave me the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer layer1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, 3]
```

I have two questions about this:

1) Why is my network receiving an input of shape `[None, None, 3]`, when as we have seen, the data read by the iterator is of shape `[64, 64, 3]`.

2) Why isn't the shape of the input actually `[1, 64, 64, 3]`, i.e. with 4 dimensions? I thought that the first dimension would be 1 because this is the batch size (I am not batching the data, so effectively this is a batch size of 1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The shape is `None` in the spatial dimensions because in principle you could be loading images of any size. There is no guarantee that they will be 64x64 so Tensorflow uses `None` shapes to allow for inputs of any size. Since you know that the images will always be the same size, you can use a `Tensor`'s `set_shape` method to give this information. Just include a line `image_float.set_shape((64, 64, 3))` in your parse function. Note that this seems to modify the tensor in place. There is even an example using images [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape).
2. You are not batching the data, so no batch axis is added at all. The elements of the dataset are simply images of shape (64, 64, 3) and these elements are returned one by one by the iterator. If you want batches of size 1 you should use `dataset = dataset.batch(1)`. Now the elements of the dataset are image "batches" of shape (1, 64, 64, 3). Of course you could also use any other method to add an axis in front, such as `tf.expand_dims`.

Comment: Thanks -- I tried both of your solutions, and they worked well.